# How to use GNU parallel with find -exec?

Tags: bash, unzip, gnu-parallel, gnu-findutils

I want to unzip multiple files,

Using [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/518376/569707), I found the following command.

`find -name '*.zip' -exec sh -c 'unzip -d "${1%.*}" "$1"' _ {} \;`

How do I use GNU Parallel with the above command to unzip multiple files?

---

Edit 1:
As per questions by user [Mark Setchell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2836621/mark-setchell)

> Where are the files ?

All the zip files are generally in a single directory.

But, as per my assumption, the command finds all the files even if recursively/non-recursively according to the depth given in find command.

> How are the files named?

`abcd_sdfa_fasfasd_dasd14.zip`

> how do you normally unzip a single one?

`unzip abcd_sdfa_fasfasd_dasd14.zip -d abcd_sdfa_fasfasd_dasd14`

Comment: Where are the files - in a single directory or spread across a hierarchy of directories? How are the files named and how do you normally unzip a single one?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can first use `find` with the `-print0` option to NULL delimit files and then read back in GNU parallel with the NULL delimiter and apply the unzip

```
find . -type f -name '*.zip' -print0 | parallel -0 unzip -d {/.} {}
```

The part `{/.}` applies string substitution to get the basename of the file and removes the part preceding the `.` as seen from the [GNU parallel documentation - See 7. Get basename, and remove last (`{.}`) or any (`{:}`) extension](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_alternatives.html) You can further set the number of parallel jobs that can be run with the `-j` flag. e.g. `-j8`, `-j64`

Answer (score 5):

You could also using the `+` variant of `-exec`. It starts `parallel` after `find` has completed, but also allows for you to still use `-print`/`-printf`/`-ls`/etc. and possibly abort the find before executing the command:

```
find . -type f -name '*.zip' -ls -exec parallel unzip -d {.} ::: {} \+
```

Note that GNU Parallel also uses `{}` to specify the input arguments. In this case, however, we use `{.}` to strip the extension like shown in your example. You can override the GNU Parallel's replacement string `{}` with `-I` (for example, using `-I@@` allows for you to use `@@` instead of `{}`).

I recommend using GNU Parallel's `--dry-run` flag or prepending `unzip` with an `echo` to test the command first and see what would be executed.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work using GNU Parallel 20221122, for example. There, the `--dry-run` option shows that it tries to execute commands like `unzip -d ./NAME_WITHOUT_EXTENSION` (without the name of the zip file). Also, this construction lacks the safeguards of the `find . -type f -name '*.zip' -print0 | parallel -0 unzip -d {/.} {}` answer  against spaces and carriage returns in filenames.